# What's the difference betweenグズ野郎 andクソ野郎

Tags: word-choice

They mean the same thing or is there a difference?

Comment: Are you sure you are asking about グズ but not クズ? グズ has a rather distict meaning which you can find in a dictionary.

Comment: Please provide more detail and context. How did you arrive to this question? Have you asked anyone else, and if so, what were their thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Both words are used when people abuse someone. However グズ is used for people who are slow to act and judge something, that is "slowpoke", "irresolute person".